# Will an ND filter lower flash output more than high speed sync?

Tags: flash, portrait, neutral-density, sunlight, high-speed-sync

I understand that both can allow for bigger apertures to be used in bright daylight but I am a little confused about the pros and cons. 
Will high speed sync lower your flash output more compared to putting a ND filter over it?

Which is preferred for portraits in bright sunlight?

Comment: If light is really too bright, you'll want to use a filter to diminish it globally. The flash (and lamps/reflectors) will then be able to allow you to highlight the desired features of the scene to make them "stand out", without over-brightening it.

Answer (score 2):

A lot depends on the flash system in question and exactly what shutter speed you are shooting due to the ambient light. With most HSS flash systems, the shorter the Tv, the more power you loose. So, purely theoretically, 1/1000 second may be more efficient to use HSS. If you need 1/8000 second to control the sun unfiltered, it might be more efficient to use an ND filter to allow the flash at full power at sync speed. In the end it is really more about the relative brightness of the ambient and the flash than anything else. The preferred method is to use reflectors to redirect the ambient in addition to using the flash, to add more flash power, or both.

Comment: I don't think that at fast shutter speeds ND filter would be preferable. Remember that the flash goes through the ND filter and the faster the shutter speed would be without ND filter, the more stops the ND filter needs to have. So an ND filter in bright conditions does in fact reduce flash power. Actually, my answer shows that at fast shutter speeds, the drawback of HSS losing light decreases, and at shutter speeds slightly faster than the flash sync speed, HSS loses to ND filters.

Comment: @juhist You're arguing against something I did not say. I said if you need 1/8000 to control the sun's brightness when unfiltered, then using an ND filter sufficient to use the camera **at sync speed** would allow the flash to use full power and have a better power ratio to the ambient than if you used an unfiltered lens at 1/8000 with HSS.

Answer (score 0):

ND filter is more cumbersome to use but always loses less light than high speed sync. The reason is two-fold.

Firstly, the total amount of flash light energy measured in lumen-seconds is reduced if you use high speed sync. Secondly, with high speed sync you are exposing with a shutter curtain system that loses more light than an ND filter would lose.

For example, let's consider a camera with 1/200 flash sync speed. If you use it without high speed sync and with flash, this is how it works:

---

0 ms: shutter first curtain begins to open, sensor 0% open

5 ms: sensor fully open, shutter second curtain begins to close

10 ms: shutter second curtain is fully closed, sensor 0% open

---

So the curve of how much sensor is open goes from 0% to 100% to 0%. The average is 50%.

If you use it without high speed sync, at 5 ms the flash quickly fires with a fully open sensor. 0% of light lost.

If you use it with high speed sync at this flash sync speed, the flash begins it output at 0 ms and ends it output at 10 ms. High speed sync is a misnomer, actually it's slower than normal flash. The flash goes through sensor curtains that are on average 50% closed, 50% open. So half of light lost.

Fortunately, the situation is better with faster shutter speeds. For example you might compare 1/3200 shutter speed with high speed sync and 1/200 shutter speed with ND16 filter.

At 1/3200, the shutter curtains work as follows:

---

0 ms: shutter first curtain begins to open, sensor 0% open

0.3125 ms: shutter second curtain begins to close, sensor 6.25% open

5 ms: shutter first curtain has ended its motion, sensor 6.25% open

5.3125 ms: shutter second curtain has ended its motion, sensor 0% open

---

So the average open area of sensor is:

```
(6.25*(5-0.3125) + 6.25*0.3125/2*2)/5.3125 = 5.8824 %
```

With ND16 filter, you would get 6.25% light through. So with 1/3200 shutter speed and HSS, you get `5.8824 / 6.25 * 100% = 94.1%` of the light you would get with an ND16 filter. 5.9% of light is lost.

This is with an ideal flash that doesn't reduce its lumen-seconds with HSS. Unfortunately, real flashes reduce the lumen-seconds available.

Let us consider 1/500 shutter speed. It works as follows:

---

0 ms: shutter first curtain begins to open, sensor 0% open

2 ms: shutter second curtain begins to close, sensor 40% open

5 ms: shutter first curtain has ended its motion, sensor 40% open

7 ms: shutter second curtain has ended its motion, sensor 0% open

---

So the average open area of sensor is:

```
(40*(5-2) + 40*2/2*2)/7 = 28.571 %
```

So with 1/500 shutter speed, you get 28.571% of the light, which means `sqrt(0.28571) = 0.5345` times the guide number.

According to https://www.scantips.com/lights/flashbasics1c3.html Nikon SB700 has a guide number of 91.9 feet. However, with high-speed sync and 1/500 shutter speed, it's 42 feet. So you get 0.457 times the guide number, not 0.5345 times the guide number.

`sqrt(0.209)` is 0.457 so you get only 20.9% of the light, not 28.571%. There's an additional about 27% light loss, coming from the use of high speed sync, over the effect that the shutter curtains cause.

So if your goal is to overpower the sun with flash, ND filter gives a slight advantage. But with a bright enough flash close enough to the subject, with light rays only filling the frame and not more, the flash might be powerful enough anyway in which case it doesn't matter since the flash isn't operating at full power anyway.